# Problema al ordenar unas tablas en una vista Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-blade

Tengo una sola tabla que muestro en una vista en laravel y resulta que quiero que esa **misma tabla** (no creando otra) se muestre ordenada horizontalmente en **diferentes tablas** de acuerdo a los datos recibidos, repitiendo su estructura con un `@foreach`.

En un primer momento lo logré mostrar *(sin ocupar un `@foreach`)*; la tabla copiando su estructura en diferentes tablas. Pero como estoy trabajando con bases de datos no me sirve así.

Esto porque estas tablas aparecen de forma automática según un valor que viene directamente desde la BD, la tabla corresponde a un complejo específico, *que viene de una vista anterior,* con canchas (específicas por complejo) de deportes, tenis, fútbol, basquetbol, etc; y **estas se deben separar en distintas tablas. Y son las tablas que intento ordenar**

¿Hay algún modo de que me queden ordenadas horizontalmente sin repetir intencionalmente las tablas?

Con intencional me refiero a lo siguiente como ejemplo *(Así no deberia ser)*:

```
<table id="table1">
    <tr><td>Cancha 1</td></tr>
</table>

<table id="table2">
    <tr><td>Cancha 2</td></tr>
</table>

<table id="table3>
    <tr><td>Cancha 3</td></tr>
</table>"
```

---

De esta manera muestro las tablas *(Como debería ser)*

```
@if($cuenta->canchas > 1 && $contar->horarios > 1)
    @foreach($horarios as $horario)
        @if($cancha->complejo_id == $complejo)
            <div class="tabla">
                <table width="570" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Horarios</th>
                        <th>Cancha</th>
                        <th>Deporte</th>
                        <th>Estado</th>
                        <th>-</th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="table-hover">
                        @if($horario->estado == 1)
                            <td>{{$horario->hora_inicio}}</td>
                            <td>{{$horario->cancha}}</td>
                            <td>{{$horario->deporte}}</td>
                            <td><button  disabled="disabled" class="btn_bussy">OCUPADO</button></td>
                            <td></td>
                        @else
                            <form method="POST"  action="{{route('reservar-confirmar',['complejo'=>$complejo])}}">                    
                                <td>{{$horario->hora_inicio}}</td>
                                <td>{{$horario->cancha}}</td>
                                <td>{{$horario->deporte}}</td>
                                <td><button disabled="disabled" class="btn_ready">DISPONIBLE</button></td>
                                {!! Form::token() !!}
                                <td>
                                    <input type="submit" name="guardar" class="btn btn-danger" id="btn-seleccionar" value="SELECCIONAR">
                                </td>
                            </form>
                        @endif      
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Y de esta forma se me ve.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Cuando quiero que queden de esta manera *(para mostrarlo de esta manera repetí las tablas intencionalmente sin ocupar un **`@foreach`** para ordenarlas)*

Así me gustaría que se vea:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cómo determinas «que no quepan en la pantalla»?

Comment: Es por la clase ocupo 1 y esa está como flotante a la izquierda (`float:left`) y al ocupar `@foreach` me debe repetir todo y por ende si ya no cabe pasará a la siguiente linea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que sacar la cabecera de la tabla del foreach, sino te lo va a repetir también

Prueba así, a ver

```
@if($cuenta->canchas > 1 && $contar->horarios > 1)
    @if($cancha->complejo_id == $complejo)
        <div class="tabla">
            <table width="570" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Horarios</th>
                    <th>Cancha</th>
                    <th>Deporte</th>
                    <th>Estado</th>
                    <th>-</th>
                </tr>
            @foreach($horarios as $horario)
                <tr class="table-hover">
                    @if($horario->estado == 1)
                        <td>{{$horario->hora_inicio}}</td>
                        <td>{{$horario->cancha}}</td>
                        <td>{{$horario->deporte}}</td>
                        <td><button  disabled="disabled" class="btn_bussy">OCUPADO</button></td>
                        <td></td>
                    @else
                        <form method="POST"  action="{{route('reservar-confirmar',['complejo'=>$complejo])}}">                    
                            <td>{{$horario->hora_inicio}}</td>
                            <td>{{$horario->cancha}}</td>
                            <td>{{$horario->deporte}}</td>
                            <td><button disabled="disabled" class="btn_ready">DISPONIBLE</button></td>
                            {!! Form::token() !!}
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" name="guardar" class="btn btn-danger" id="btn-seleccionar" value="SELECCIONAR">
                            </td>
                        </form>
                    @endif      
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </table>
        </div>
    @endif
```

@endif

Comment: Mmm ya veo te refieres al `@foreach` dejarlo en el cuerpo de la tabla, ya probé así y me repite todo hacia abajo, la idea es que me quedara ordenada una al lado de otra y las demás se van moviendo hacia abajo. Por eso el `@foreach` lo puse al comienzo del `<div>`

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres es mostrar dos tablas y quieres q vallan intercalando entre si los datos yo pusiera en una tabla los datos pares, en el otro los impares. Ejemplo

```
@foreach($horarios as $horario)
   @if($loop->index % 2 == 0)
       <tr>
            //bla bla bla
       </tr>
    @endif
@endforeach

@foreach($horarios as $horario)
   @if($loop->index % 2 == 1)
       <tr>
            //bla bla bla
       </tr>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

La documentacion de `$loop` variable puedes verla [aqui](https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#the-loop-variable)

Comment: No amigo asi no me funciona. sigue igual.